Power BI - Paginated report with REST API data source

Is Power BI Paginated Report support REST API as data source
If yes, how to configure the authentication (like client_credentails)?

Thanks for your help,
Anh

Yes you can connect to an API via a URL or if the API is already a supported datasource you can connect to it via authentication.

To connect to a data source, create a new report and you will be prompted to Add data to your report.
You will see options to import data from excel, import data from SQL Server, paste data into a blank table, use sample data or there is alternative option to Get data from another source which you should choose if you want to use an API.
Since you have not provided what API you are using, I cannot say if there is an available data source you could choose besides the WEB option to import data from a webpage. Once you select it, you will need to provide a URL to the API.
